# Antlr4 ignoring newlines at all but one point

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am writing a parser for a scripting language, and using antlr 4.5.3 for the     purpose.

```
grammar VSE;

chunk
    : block* EOF
    ;

block
    : var '=' exp
    | functioncall
    ;

var
    : NAME
    | var '[' exp ']'
    | var '.' var
    ;

exp
    : number
    | string
    | var
    | functioncall
    | <assoc=right> exp exp //concat
    ;

functioncall
    : NAME '(' (exp)? (',' exp)* ')'
    | var '.' functioncall
    ;


string
    : '"' (~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n') | '\\' ('"' | '\\'))* '"'
    ;

NAME
    : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
    ;

number
    : INT | HEX | FLOAT
    ;

INT
    : Digit+
    ;

HEX
    : '0' [xX] [0-9a-fA-F]+
    ;

FLOAT
    : Digit* '.' Digit+ 
    ;

Digit
    : [0-9]
    ;

WS  
    : [ \t\u000C\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;
```

However, while testing it, I found a variable assignment like `var = something` followed by some function call in next line leads to a concat statement. (My concat statement is a variable followed by another like `var = var1 var2`) I understand that antlr is skipping ALL the new lines in favor of line continuation, but I'd like to add the condition that if there is a new line between two `exp`s, it would treat them as two separate blocks instead of a concat statement. i.e.

```
var = var2
functioncall(var)
```

These should be two separate blocks instead of concat statement.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following rule suitable for you?

```
block
    : var '=' exp NEW_LINE
    | functioncall NEW_LINE
    ;

NEW_LINE: '\r'? '\n'

WS  
    : [ \t]+ -> skip
    ;
```

In another case you should use [Semantic Predicates](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md) or very unclear grammar.

Comment: That works fine if I use just assignment and function call. However, If it breaks line continuation for every other thing. Is there any way to do this without adding an optional NEW_LINE everywhere?